# Не вводится пароль в git

Tags: git

При клонирования удаленного репозитория

```
git clone http://<username>@site.com/gerrit/p/kontakt <myfile>
```

получаю ответ:

```
Cloning into '<myfile>'... 
password for 'http://<username>@site.com/gerrit/p/kontakt':
```

Пробовал ввести сгенерированный пароль, почему то вообще не вводится, как можно решить? ОС win7, программа Git Bash

Comment: Оо Боже, пошли мне ответчика!)

Comment: Просто вводите пароль с клавиатуры. Необязательно, что он при этом будет отображаться или будет видно, что вводятся символы.

Comment: "Cloning into '<myfile>'" - сначала это? Потом у git у Вас просит пароль. Вы его вводите и что он пишет? 
то что Вы написали это вроде как приглашение ввести пароль... Что потом пишет?

Comment: Пробовал ввести пароль не смотря на то что не отображается символы, ошибка:
fatal: Authentication failed

Comment: значит не верно введен пароль

Comment: Все сработал, Вы были правы KryDos & gecube , спаисбо за помощь!!!

Comment: Еще один момент, когда работаю иногда появляется (END) и все дальше нет движений, как можно этой убрать?

Comment: Нажмите ![](http://i.imgur.com/Vzc0J.png)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Не могу ввести пароль в терминале](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/442416/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%83-%d0%b2%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c-%d0%b2-%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bc%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b5)