# Не могу ввести пароль в терминале

Tags: unix, faq

Установил первый раз *linux mint 17.2* и не могу ввести пароль в терминале:

ничего не появляется при вводе пароля.

Если я нажму <kbd>Enter</kbd>, то получаю ошибку:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как ввести пароль?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

В целях безопасности пароль при вводе не отображается. Попробуйте ввести комбинацию клавиш, содержащую Ваш пароль и нажать Enter

Comment: Спасибо вам от души!