# Не вводится пароль при первом пуше в Github

Tags: git, github

Пытаюсь залить на Github папку. Делаю всё по гайду:

1. Создаю репозиторий на сайте
2. Создаю пустую папку
3. В командой строке через `cd` перехожу в директорию папки и
   инициализирую git командой

   ```
   git init
   ```
4. Копирую туда нужные папки и html/php файлы
5. командой git add . добавляю их под контроль версий
6. потом идут 3 команды для коммита и пуша:

   ```
   git commit -m "first commit"
   git remote add origin https://github.com/Avoska/shablon.git
   git push -u origin master
   ```

после чего просит ввести логин и пароль

проблема в том, что когда нужно ввести пароль клавиатура перестает реагировать и что-то вводить, работает только Enter, ну и когда оставляю поле пароля пустым, закономерный результат:
[image]

Comment: Вводимый пароль просто не отображается. Это совершенно нормально при вводе пароля в консоли. Просто вводите и жмите Enter.

Comment: как дубликат можно отметить, например, этот вопрос: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/442416/178576