# Не могу создать createsuperuser в Django

Tags: python, django

Я только начал изучать Django, поэтому возможно вопрос будет глуп.

Хочу создать аккаунт для админки на http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/login/?next=/admin/ .
Для этого в консоли надо ввести `py manage.py createsuperuser`.
Там все выводится правильно, но на пункте когда нужно ввести пароль, я ничего не могу написать. Ни по русски, ни по английски, и никакие цифры. Вообще никакие символы. Из-за этого я не могу создать аккаунт для админки. Использую окно cmd, так-же попробовал и PowerShell, и запускал cmd от имени администратора. Ничего не помогает

В итоге вопрос: почему я не могу задать пароль используя команду в django `py manage.py createsuperuser`?

[image: Скрин интерфейса]

Comment: С чего вы взяли, что не можете? Если потому, что при наборе не появляются символы, так это не значит, что они не вводятся.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Не могу ввести пароль в терминале](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/442416/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%83-%d0%b2%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c-%d0%b2-%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bc%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На самом деле ввод символов производится, просто они не печатаются. Это сделано в целях безопасности, чтобы кто-то другой не подсмотрел, что вы вводите, или не скопировал, и т. п.

Answer (score 0):

столкнулся с такой же проблемой. Искал ответ (в том числе и здесь). все пишут только одно, что текст вводится, но его не видно. Но новичек видит, что курсор стоит на месте и нет никакого отзыва. оказалось все банально просто. первым выводится слово Password: надо ввести пароль и нажать Enter (при этом символы не будут появляться и курсор будет стоять на месте). потом появится надпись Password (again): необходимо в точности повторить пароль, который был введен выше. (при этом символы также не будут видны). Enter  и superuser создан.
Ответ для начинающих, коим и сам являюсь.