# установка gulp на Mac

Tags: gulp, установка, macbook

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]не могу установить gulp на Mac.
Список действий:

1. npm i gulp -D
   установился node__modules
2. npm i gulp-cli -g
   пишет ошибку могу приложить скрин , что я делаю не так
   писал sudo npm i gulp-cli -g
   не могу ввести пароль

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Не могу ввести пароль в терминале](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/442416/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%83-%d0%b2%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c-%d0%b2-%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bc%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b5)

Answer (score 0):

sudo npm i -g gulp
пароль вводится просто не видно на клавиатуре и как будто ни чего не работает.Все ок